# set textview below textview in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

first I created a relative layout and insert the first text view and its icon

RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
    tv.setText("Test");
    tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,
            0,
            R.drawable.rsz_page_pic,
            0);
    tv.setCompoundDrawablePadding(20);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    tv.setLayoutParams(rlp);
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    relativeLayout.addView(tv);
```

It's work fine with me now I want to add textview below the textview that I created above so please can any one help me I'm really sorry for my bade English and I hope you understand what I want

Comment: why don't you use LinearLayout besides of Relative Layout ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can addRule on LayoutParam for RelativeLayout

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
    tv.setText("Test");
    tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,
            0,
            R.drawable.rsz_page_pic,
            0);
    tv.setCompoundDrawablePadding(20);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    tv.setLayoutParams(rlp);
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    relativeLayout.addView(tv);
```